# How can one modify the named directory hash table by "creating appropriate shell parameters"?

Tags: shell, zsh, shell-builtin

I'm used to add entrys to `zsh`s named driectory hash table, by using `hash -d <name>=<value>`. Recently, I read the `zshbuiltins(1)` man page, where I found the following (description of the `hash` builtin):

> Normally one would modify these tables by modifying one's PATH (for the command hash table) or by creating appropriate shell  parameters
> (for the named directory hash table).

I don't understand how this `by creating appropriate shell parameters` mechanism would work. Can someone give me an example how it may be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *named directories* (in addition to users' home directories) are directories you store in variables and you can then use `~varname` to access them after which an entry is added into the hash table.

Example:

```
$ var=/usr/local
$ hash -d
$ echo ~var
/usr/local
$ hash -d
var=/usr/local
```

```
$ : ~root
$ hash -d
root=/root
var=/usr/local
```

(I never really understood the point of that feature myself)

See `info zsh 'static named directories'` for details (I wouldn't use `man` for a manual this size).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your examples. I actually misunderstood the usage of the `hash` builtin, may I edit your answer to reflect my misunderstandings?

Comment: @ixolius, sure. Not sure what you mean, but I'll be given to review your edit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The point of this feature is that it comes in really handy if you're working on multiple paths and constantly changing from one branch to another branch in the directory tree. For example, if you have two identical directory trees one rooted on `~/home/src/project/devel` and another on `~/home/src/project/production` you can then do:

`typeset -e dev=~/home/src/project/devel ; typeset -e prod=~/home/src/project/production ;`

You can conveniently use `~dev` or `~prod` as you would use `~` or `~user` in any command that takes a path as argument, v.gr:

`cp -Rav ~dev/module ~/prod to copy module from development to production. Sabes you a lot of typing on frequently used directories that you may use often. They need not be rooted on the same dir, this is just an easy use case.

I find it handy to name deeply nested directories that I visit often for reference such as `/use/local/lib/zsh/site-functions` as `~zfunc` the fact that this works for any command that takes paths makes it a very powerful shortcut.

Comment: How is that better than `dev=~/home/src/project/devel prod=~/home/src/project/production` and use `$dev` and `$prod` instead of `~dev` and `~prod` (other than the effect on prompt's `%~`)?

Comment: It has to do with the order in which expansion and substitution occurs when evaluating the command line. Parameter expansion ( `$dev` and `$prod`) happens earlier than filename expansion which is where `~nameddir` gets expanded. This is relevant specially in complex commands and scripts, and when using directory names with spaces. Say `$prod="/home/src/Production Files" ` using`$prod` in a script may get split into two words, depending on your configuration whereas `~prod` will not and it is portable.

Comment: $prod is not split in zsh and ~prod is zsh-only though.

Comment: depends on whether `SHWORD_SPLIT` option is set or not. If `zsh` is invoked as `sh` or `ksh` (it *does* happen, that's how i got this knowledge nugget, when working on an old SCO system with ksh as default shell, but zsh installed as an additional package) then `SHWORD_SPLIT` will be set and `$prod` will be split on parameter expansion. `SHWORD_SPLIT` is also set in emulation. `~prod` won't get split regardless of how `zsh` was invoked or whether care was taken to define proper emulation in scripts. (also, you're right about portability. I should have said *predictable* instead of *portable*)